# Retrieve data from MySQL Database on button click with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a html table made with my competition names, dates and every row of the table has a button, that corresponds to the competition name. What I would like to know is, if it is possible to show the results of that competition in a modal when that button is clicked? The results of each competition is stored in a separate table in the database to that of the competition names and dates.

My table at the minute is looking like this

```
echo "
      <div align = 'center'>
      <table class = 'reportTable' border = '1' cellpadding = '5' width = '90%'>
         <tr>
            <th> Competition Number </th>
            <th> Competition Name </th>
            <th> Date Of Competition </th>
            <th> Results </th>
          </tr>
          ";

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
             echo "
                  <tr align = 'center'>
                      <td>".$row['competitionID']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['competitionName']."</td>
                      <td>".date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['dateStarting']))."</td>
                      <td><a href = results.php?id=".$row['competitionID'].">Results</a></td></td>
                  </tr>
                  ";
          }

          echo "</table>
              </div>";
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a I click on a button that corresponds to the competition, it will show a modal on the page that shows the results of that competition only.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you're generating multiple submit buttons with the **SAME** id. that's invalid. DOM ids must be unique across the entire document. Other than that, exactly how is this not working for you?

Comment: the answer is yes, you have several problems in your script ... 1 - you are using the same `id` for your button over and over, this is not valid html.  2 - you should be passing the competitionID instead of the name as the ID should be a unique value.

Comment: I got rid of the id tag. Really, I am stumped on this. I don't know where to start to grab information from the database by the click of a button, and display the right information, depending on what button is clicked. Would a screenshot explain more?

Comment: @BudgieBr0phy: It sounds like you might want to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP and MySQL in that case.  Querying a database and displaying the results is pretty fundamental functionality.  Essentially you would send the ID value to the server (either as a form post or an AJAX post) which has a page that reads the ID, uses it in a SELECT query, and outputs the results in a loop.

Comment: @David I understand how to do all that perfectly fine. What I would like some enlightment on is how to select the data depending on the button selected. I have multiple competitions, and therefor, multiple buttons. How do I grab the correct information is what I would like to know.

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.gyazo.com/0e80f8ff4db72400ac2bc125d0cf7fcd.png

Comment: _“The results of each competition is stored in a separate table”_ – why separate tables? Assuming the data structure is identical, they should be in one and the same table.

Comment: @BudgieBr0phy: That's where you'd use the ID for that competition.  The form post (or AJAX request) would include a value for that ID.  It could be as simple as a link, something like: `<a href="results.php?id=123">Results</a>`  Dynamically populate "123" with the competition ID from your data, and "Results" with the competition Name.  Each of those links would go to the `results.php` page which would read that ID and display the data for that ID.

Comment: _“How do I grab the correct information is what I would like to know”_ – you pass the information that uniquely identifies that data to your server-side script, and let it select the records from the database based on that.

Comment: Sorry, the reults of all competitions are stored in the one table called compResults, not separate tables for each individual competition. Error on my part

Comment: Your submit button needs quotes around the `value` attribute - presently it doesn't have any, and so any string therein will be unbounded (invalid HTML).

Comment: Your best bet is bootstrap and jquery. You will be amazed at quick you get the results

Comment: You should learn how to do a classic form with a normal submit button before you try to do AJAX. Otherwise you're just going to confuse yourself by not understanding client/server well enough.

Answer (score -1):

This is the format of your `<input>` tag at the moment. The quotes you are using are string delimiters in PHP, not quotes in the tag. Thus two attributes don't have quotes:

```
<input type = 'submit' value = PGA id = 6>
```

It is better to add in quotes and strip spaces, thus:

```
<input type='submit' value='PGA' id='6'>
```

You've edited the code to include an attribute of `value = value =`, which I assume is just an editing mistake.

If you want to read a value from the form based on the competition PK, you could do something like this:

```
<input type='submit' name="competition[6]" value='PGA' id='6'>
```

You can then examine `$_POST['competition']` upon form submission to see which competition was clicked on (it'll be an array).

Comment: I have updated the code so that the result id gets passed to another page. I can create the page to show the information from the database, but how do I make use of the id being passed to grab the information? 

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: In your input tag you should have a `name="foo"`. In the page you are submitting to you will access it via `$_GET['foo']` or `$_POST['foo']` (depends on the `method` of your form. If you don't care whether it is GET or POST then you can just use `$_REQUEST['foo']`.

Comment: @Budgie, using the technique I outline in my post, you now have a competition ID using a traditional form submission (this isn't a fancy AJAX op suitable for a modal, but one step at a time). You then take the competition ID, presumably an integer, and feed it into a database query, to get details relating to that competition. Since this is a read operation, a `get` method form would be fine here. Once you have query results, you can then render them on the page.

Comment: Ah, I see you've updated your question to use a link instead of a form. That's fine - the `id` can be read from the next page using `$_GET['id']` and fed into the query I describe above.